# What is the "His glorious inheritance" mentioned in Ephesians 1:18?

Tags: new-testament, ephesians, pauline-epistles

What is the "His glorious inheritance" mentioned in

> Ephesians 1:18 having the eyes of your hearts enlightened, that you
>   may know what is the hope to which he has called you, what are the
>   riches of his glorious inheritance in the saints,

?

1. What did God (or Christ) inherit?
2. From whom did He inherit?
3. What are the riches of it?
4. How does the saint experience it?

Comment: 'His' refers back to _the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of glory_ in verse 17. It does not refer to Christ, as such.

Comment: @NigelJ changed the first question accordingly

Comment: The questions allowed on this site must comply with enquiries in the field of grammatico-historical interpretation. Although the section is called Biblical hermeneutics, it is a misnomer, because the section actually deals with ONE of the types of Biblical hermeneutics, literal, the others being moral, allegorical, and anagogical. This means you should ask questions like, “Is there anything in the grammar of Ephesians 2: 8 which will reveal if ‘this’ refers to ‘faith’ or ‘grace’?”. Or “Is there any historical situation that reveals why covering the hair in 1 Cor 11:6 is prescribed?”.

Comment: The inheritance is the new covenant Heb 9:155For this reason He is the mediator of a new covenant, so that, since a death has taken place for the redemption of the transgressions that were committed under the first covenant, those who have been called may receive the promise of the eternal inheritance.

Comment: @Seeker the Ephesian 1:18 inheritance is God’s and the Hebrew 9 inheritance is the believer’s you are conflating the two.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo In Heb 9 the writer states an unchanging principle: no will is executed unless the testator dies. In Eph 1:18, who died? Or, who gave the inheritance? Definitely not the sons of God or the ruler of this age.

Comment: Jesus died! We died to ourselves! And as psalm 82 says “Arise, O God, judge the earth; for you shall inherit all the nations!”
‭‭Psalms‬ ‭82:8‬ ‭Who dies here in this instance?

Comment: Psalms 82:8 does not describe the situation of an inheritance bequeathed through the execution of the last will and testament of a testator who has died. It is better understood as the taking over possession of a property wrongly held by a tresspasser.

Comment: Eph 1:9 NASB He made known to us the mystery of His will, according to His kind intention which He purposed in Him 10with a view to an administration suitable to the fullness of the times, that is, the summing up of all things in Christ, things in the heavens and things on the earth. In Him 11also **we have obtained an inheritance**, having been predestined according to His purpose who works all things after the counsel of His will, 12to the end that we who were the first to hope in Christ would be to the praise of His glory. Bold format done by me to show "we" inherit.

Comment: @seeker no one is denying that we (I) have an inheritance among the saints, but the passage explicitly states that God is inheriting something in/through the saints. So it’s His inheritance that the OP is asking about. You are conflating the two as if you say God doesn’t have an inheritance too.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo You said Eph 1 is bout God's inheritance, but v11 is clearly about our inheritance.

Comment: Yes and I don’t dispute v11 is about our inheritance and v18 about God’s. @Seeker

Comment: Then why should the topic switch from one to the other? One way to decide is to see if inheritance in v18 is subjective genitive or objective genitive in the Greek...by the context?

Comment: @Seeker and what did you find? As for why would the subject change? Because Apostle Paul is making a different point? Actually there are several points running through the chapter and they culminate. “he predestined us **for adoption to himself as sons through Jesus Christ**, according to the purpose of his will,”
‭‭Ephesians‬ ‭1:5‬ ‭this is what v18 is saying. It’s not a new topic it’s a weave of multiple subjects

Comment: I've read several outlines and commentaries on Ephesians. They all agree that the inheritance, and other blessings, are FOR the saints. This is the theme running through the entire epistle. That should be more than enough context to decide that inheritance is subjective genitive. The inheritance is for the believers, God's gift to them, found complete, IN the saints.

Answer (score 2):

**What did God (or Christ) inherit?**

Every will has an inheritance involved, to be given to a beneficiary. The heirs inherited the New Covenant, which is the inheritance of the Will and Testament of Christ.

> Hebrews 9:15 NASB For this reason He is the mediator of a new covenant, so that, since a death has taken place for the redemption of the transgressions that were committed under the first covenant, those who have been called may receive the promise of the eternal inheritance.

**From whom did He inherit?**

Christ being the first fruit, beneficiary of the Will and Testament, inherited it from the Testator of that Will.

> Hebrews 9:17 KJV For a testament is in force after men are dead, since it has no power at all while the testator lives.

**What are the riches of it?**

The riches of the Will is that the promise to Abraham, to be blessings to the world, might come to the People of God, spiritual Israel, sheep of both flocks, through the giving of the Holy Spirit.

> Galatians 3:14 NASB He redeemed us in order that the blessing promised to Abrahamg would come to the Gentiles in Christ Jesus, so that by faith we might receive the promise of the Spirit.

**How does the saint experience it?**

The Saint experiences it by not being like Israel of the flesh, with whom God was not pleased, and of whom He swore would not enter His Rest, because of disobedience to the call of God.

> Hebrews 4: 6 NASB Therefore, since it remains for some to enter it, and those who formerly had good news preached to them failed to enter because of disobedience,
>
> 7He again fixes a certain day, “Today,” saying through David after so long a time just as has been said before,
>    “TODAY IF YOU HEAR HIS VOICE,
>     DO NOT HARDEN YOUR HEARTS.”
>
> 8For if Joshua had given them rest, He would not have spoken of another day after that. 9So there remains a Sabbath rest for the people of God. 10For the one who has entered His rest has himself also rested from his works, as God did from His. 11Therefore let us be diligent to enter that rest, so that no one will fall, through following the same example of disobedience.

Answer (score 2):

**What did God (or Christ) inherit?**

He inherited the saints from all nations

**From whom did He inherit?**

He inherited it from the sons of God and from the ruler of this age by purchasing the whole world and buying back the title deed of the world. As per Psalm 82 and Matthew 4:8

**What are the riches of it?**

The riches is the life of Christ or “Christ in you” as per Colossians  1:27

**How does the saint experience it?**

By walking in the light and believing in the name of His Son Jesus Christ

#### Theological outworkings

This passage makes it clear even in the English translation that this inheritance is IN the saints.

Put differently they are the inheritance, they are the glorious inheritance. The more pertinent question is who is ‘they’? But since that is not the question let’s deal with this inheritance and rich treasure that God has in the saints.

> “Arise, shine; For your light has come! And the glory of the LORD is risen upon you. **For behold, the darkness shall cover the earth, And deep darkness the people**; But the LORD will arise over you, And His glory will be seen upon you. The Gentiles shall come to your light, And kings to the brightness of your rising. “Lift up your eyes all around, and see: They all gather together, they come to you; Your sons shall come from afar, And your daughters shall be nursed at your side. Then you shall see and become radiant, And your heart shall swell with joy; Because the abundance of the sea shall be turned to you, **The wealth of the Gentiles shall come to you**.”
> ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭60:1-5‬ ‭

The Greek word used in Ephesians πλουτος (riches) same word here used in the LXX.

God was going to inherit the nations back to himself from the sons of God who corrupted themselves.

> “When the Most High gave to the nations their inheritance, when he divided mankind, he fixed the borders of the peoples **according to the number of the sons of God**.”
> ‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭32:8‬ ‭ESV‬‬ (LXX, DSS)

This of course happened at the Tower of Babel when Nimrod the world leader persuaded the entire world population to rebel against God! The God of Heaven (The Most High) put over humans gods or sons of God or the elohim according to their new language and grouping.

But as mentioned earlier the elohim corrupted themselves and did not represent God but even took worship for themselves thus becoming the gods of the nations.

> “God has taken his place in the divine council; **in the midst of the gods** he holds judgment: "How long will you judge unjustly and show partiality to the wicked? Selah
> They have neither knowledge nor understanding, **they (humans) walk about in darkness**; all the foundations of the earth are shaken. I said, "**You are gods, sons of the Most High**, all of you; nevertheless, like men you shall die, and fall like any prince."”
> ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭82:1-2, 5-7‬ ‭

It is remarkable that humans are in darkness and this parallels with the passage in Isaiah and in the gospels

> “In him was life, and the life was the light of men. The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭1:4-5‬ ‭

And that, the sons of God were  meant to show men the light of the Most High ( which is The LIFE that was promised to Eve/woman Genesis 3:15 in regaining fellowship with God again and therefore paradise) but they didn’t show men the light that they might turn back to God and live and now comes Jesus to show men that Light, yes as God incarnate but representing the Father.

And notice the key verse in psalm 82

> “Arise, O God, judge the earth; **for you shall inherit all the NATIONS**!”
> ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭82:8‬ ‭

This brings in a different answer I gave to a different question how the nations come into the new covenant and how the the lost tribes of Israel are accepted back in though they were once divorced.

[Ten Lost Tribes and the Gentiles](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/41256/in-romans-1126-how-is-all-understood-by-those-who-believe-israel-refers-to-p/41265#41265)

> “And nations shall come to your light, and kings to the brightness of your rising.”
> ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭60:3‬ ‭

And the riches of the nations are those who will accept Jesus Christ as their Lord and Savior and thereby enter into the new covenant and become that inheritance of the nations that God will inherit at the final judgment.

Because God actually loves all men but will only accept those who accept to be with Him out of love for Him. That’s why

> “"For **God so loved the world**, that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life. For **God did not send his Son into the world to condemn the world**, but in order that the world might be saved through him. Whoever believes in him is not condemned, but whoever does not believe is condemned already, because he has not believed in the name of the only Son of God. **And this is the judgment: the light has come into the world, and people loved the darkness rather than the light** because their works were evil. For everyone who does wicked things hates the light and does not come to the light, lest his works should be exposed. **But whoever does what is true comes to the light**, so that it may be clearly seen that **his works have been carried out in God**."”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭3:16-21‬ ‭

Notice that last phrase his works (righteousness) was carried out in God in other words it wasn’t their own righteousness and it wasn’t of the flesh.

And this glorious inheritance is in the saints because they have accepted This glorious light to be in them and therefore **eternal life**! They have accepted to seek the kingdom and His RIGHTEOUSNESS and having had it imputed to them they walk in the light and have fellowship with God.

> “But if we walk in the light, as he is in the light, we have fellowship with one another, and the blood of Jesus his Son cleanses us from all sin.”
> ‭‭1 John‬ ‭1:7‬ ‭

This is right after these words were written

“This is the message we have heard from him and proclaim to you, that God is light, and in him is no darkness at all. If we say we have fellowship with him while we walk in darkness, we lie and do not practice the truth.”
‭‭1 John‬ ‭1:5-6‬ ‭

This is only possible in Jesus

> “And this is **eternal life**, that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom you have sent.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭17:3‬ ‭

We are the glorious inheritance, we the saints are that glorious inheritance because we have accepted the Son and therefore the light and no longer stand in judgment but will be with Him and He will therefore inherit us all.

We are precious in God’s eyes is what Apostle Paul is saying and he wanted the early Church to realize that they were a glorious inheritance to God.

Comment: “To them God chose to make known how great among the Gentiles are the riches of the glory of this mystery, **which is Christ in you**, the hope of glory.”
‭‭Colossians‬ ‭1:27‬ ‭that’s what makes the saints the inheritance and the treasure as per Matthew 13:44 is Christ in the saint.

Comment: @NihilSineDeoThank you for the detailed answer :-), He could not inherit it from rules of the age as inheritance means ["an inheritance, an heritage, **regularly the gift of God to His chosen people**, in the Old Testament: the Promised Land, in NT a possession viewed in one sense as present, in another as future; a share, participation."](https://biblehub.com/greek/2817.htm)

Comment: If the inheritance is the saints then how can it be **"in the"** saints? What is **"in the"** saints which is called his inheritance? Or am I just confused because I am a non-native English speaker?

Comment: You need to differentiate between the body and the spirit @SijuGeorge. The saint is not the earthen vessel that will return to dust, that is the flesh and its corrupted by sin. God will not inherit the sinful body of the saint rather He will inherit the seed which He planted in the saint. *“Whoever has been born of God does not sin, *for His seed remains in him*; and he cannot sin, because he has been born of God.”
‭‭I John‬ ‭3:9‬* and the seed is the Word and the Word is Jesus. Just as also are born of the seed of Adam now we are born of the seed of the last Adam Jesus.

Comment: God will inherit a harvest of ‘souls’ (spirits) who are born again of the Spirit and therefore of God. This is what God wants an inheritance of saints (spirits in carnal bodies) from every nation to which He will give glorified bodies and be with God forever. God is looking forward to inheriting a world full of people (spirits born of Christ) that will spend eternity with Him because they want to spend eternity with Him. You have to distinguish between the carnal body and the spirit which is the new man/spirit/inheritance

Comment: @SijuGeorge notice in the definition it says **regularly** that does not mean always but on most occasions. Therefore it does not exclude God from receiving an inheritance. It just means it’s not a common occurrence. It’s most often the case that God gives the inheritance but most often is not always the rule. Clearly Psalm 82 reads “Arise, O God, judge the earth; For You shall inherit all nations.”
‭‭Psalms‬ ‭82:8‬ ‭Therefore God is getting the inheritance and not men as it’s most common or regularly the case.

Answer (score 2):

According to the context we have the Apostle Paul stating at Ephesians 1:13-14 stating, "In Him, you also, after listening to the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation--having also believed, you were sealed in Him with the Holy Spirit of promise, vs14, who is given as a pledge or our inheritance, with a view to the redemption of God's own possession, to the praise of His glory."

The word "redemption" in the Greek is "apolutrosin) refers to the culmination of the process which will become a reality when Jesus returns to this earth and believers are resurrected. Since this is true Paul is praying (vs17) that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of glory, may give to you a spirit of wisdom and of revelation in the knowledge of Him."

Paul is desiring for believers that they would comprehend fully what they had received in Jesus Christ. So at vs18 Paul first says believers are to grow properly in the Lord, they must understand the "hope of their calling." Also, understanding "God's inheritance in the saints" will lead to growth in the Lord. The Bible speaks in many places about the inheritance God has promised His people, but in this verse there is a locative case expression in the Greek which literally means "in the sphere of the saints."

Obviously, God does not "need" anything from us. However, He does "want our praise (see verses 6,12,14). When Christians truly realize they are the only part of God's creation that can praise God WILLINGLY because we have experienced salvation, it should give tremendous motivation toward spiritual maturity. Vs19-23 expands on the greatness of His power toward us who believed. Philippians 2:13 come to mind, "for it is God who is at work in you, both to will and to work for His good pleasure."

Answer (score 1):

The identification of the LORD's inheritance is said by Moses to be "his People" and he places them in parallel with "the LORD's portion" indicating to me that by "the LORD's inheritance" he is refer to the kingdom that he will bequeath to his son:

> [Deu 32:5-14 NIV] (5) They are corrupt and not his children; to their shame they are a warped and crooked generation. (6) Is this the way you repay the LORD, you foolish and unwise people? Is he not your Father, your Creator, who made you and formed you? (7) Remember the days of old; consider the generations long past. Ask your father and he will tell you, your elders, and they will explain to you. **(8) When the Most High gave the nations their inheritance, when he divided all mankind, he set up boundaries for the peoples according to the number of the sons of Israel. (9) For the LORD's portion is his people, Jacob his allotted inheritance.** (10) In a desert land he found him, in a barren and howling waste. He shielded him and cared for him; he guarded him as the apple of his eye, (11) like an eagle that stirs up its nest and hovers over its young, that spreads its wings to catch them and carries them aloft. (12) The LORD alone led him; no foreign god was with him. (13) He made him ride on the heights of the land and fed him with the fruit of the fields. He nourished him with honey from the rock, and with oil from the flinty crag, (14) with curds and milk from herd and flock and with fattened lambs and goats, with choice rams of Bashan and the finest kernels of wheat. You drank the foaming blood of the grape.

Christ is the heir of the kingdom of God (the vineyard of God):

> [Mar 12:1-12 NIV] (1) Jesus then began to speak to them in parables: "A man planted a **vineyard**. He put a wall around it, dug a pit for the winepress and built a watchtower. Then he rented the vineyard to some farmers and moved to another place. (2) At harvest time he sent a servant to the tenants to collect from them some of the fruit of the vineyard. (3) But they seized him, beat him and sent him away empty-handed. (4) Then he sent another servant to them; they struck this man on the head and treated him shamefully. (5) He sent still another, and that one they killed. He sent many others; some of them they beat, others they killed. **(6) "He had one left to send, a son, whom he loved. He sent him last of all, saying, 'They will respect my son.' (7) "But the tenants said to one another, 'This is the heir. Come, let's kill him, and the inheritance will be ours.' (8) So they took him and killed him, and threw him out of the vineyard.** (9) "What then will the owner of the vineyard do? **He will come and kill those tenants and give the vineyard to others.** (10) Haven't you read this passage of Scripture: " 'The stone the builders rejected has become the cornerstone; (11) the Lord has done this, and it is marvelous in our eyes'?" (12) Then the chief priests, the teachers of the law and the elders looked for a way to arrest him because they knew he had spoken the parable against them. But they were afraid of the crowd; so they left him and went away.

To confer the blessing upon his son a man lays his hands upon his son's head and delivers all of his pronouncement. Those who are in Christ receive the same blessing just as Jacob received the blessing by hiding inside Esau:

> [Gen 27:1-46 NIV] (1) When Isaac was old and his eyes were so weak that he could no longer see, he called for Esau his older son and said to him, "My son." "Here I am," he answered. (2) Isaac said, "I am now an old man and don't know the day of my death. (3) Now then, get your equipment--your quiver and bow--and go out to the open country to hunt some wild game for me. (4) Prepare me the kind of tasty food I like and bring it to me to eat, so that I may give you my blessing before I die." (5) Now Rebekah was listening as Isaac spoke to his son Esau. When Esau left for the open country to hunt game and bring it back, (6) Rebekah said to her son Jacob, "Look, I overheard your father say to your brother Esau, (7) 'Bring me some game and prepare me some tasty food to eat, so that I may give you my blessing in the presence of the LORD before I die.' (8) Now, my son, listen carefully and do what I tell you: (9) Go out to the flock and bring me two choice young goats, so I can prepare some tasty food for your father, just the way he likes it. (10) Then take it to your father to eat, so that he may give you his blessing before he dies." (11) Jacob said to Rebekah his mother, "But my brother Esau is a hairy man while I have smooth skin. (12) What if my father touches me? I would appear to be tricking him and would bring down a curse on myself rather than a blessing." (13) His mother said to him, "My son, let the curse fall on me. Just do what I say; go and get them for me." (14) So he went and got them and brought them to his mother, and she prepared some tasty food, just the way his father liked it. (15) Then Rebekah took the best clothes of Esau her older son, which she had in the house, and put them on her younger son Jacob. (16) She also covered his hands and the smooth part of his neck with the goatskins. (17) Then she handed to her son Jacob the tasty food and the bread she had made. (18) He went to his father and said, "My father." "Yes, my son," he answered. "Who is it?" (19) Jacob said to his father, "I am Esau your firstborn. I have done as you told me. Please sit up and eat some of my game, so that you may give me your blessing." (20) Isaac asked his son, "How did you find it so quickly, my son?" "The LORD your God gave me success," he replied. (21) Then Isaac said to Jacob, "Come near so I can touch you, my son, to know whether you really are my son Esau or not." (22) Jacob went close to his father Isaac, who touched him and said, "The voice is the voice of Jacob, but the hands are the hands of Esau." (23) He did not recognize him, for his hands were hairy like those of his brother Esau; so he proceeded to bless him. (24) "Are you really my son Esau?" he asked. "I am," he replied. (25) Then he said, "My son, bring me some of your game to eat, so that I may give you my blessing." Jacob brought it to him and he ate; and he brought some wine and he drank. (26) Then his father Isaac said to him, "Come here, my son, and kiss me." (27) So he went to him and kissed him. When Isaac caught the smell of his clothes, he blessed him and said, "Ah, the smell of my son is like the smell of a field that the LORD has blessed. (28) May God give you heaven's dew and earth's richness--an abundance of grain and new wine. (29) May nations serve you and peoples bow down to you. Be lord over your brothers, and may the sons of your mother bow down to you. May those who curse you be cursed and those who bless you be blessed." (30) After Isaac finished blessing him, and Jacob had scarcely left his father's presence, his brother Esau came in from hunting. (31) He too prepared some tasty food and brought it to his father. Then he said to him, "My father, please sit up and eat some of my game, so that you may give me your blessing." (32) His father Isaac asked him, "Who are you?" "I am your son," he answered, "your firstborn, Esau." (33) Isaac trembled violently and said, "Who was it, then, that hunted game and brought it to me? I ate it just before you came and I blessed him--and indeed he will be blessed!" (34) When Esau heard his father's words, he burst out with a loud and bitter cry and said to his father, "Bless me--me too, my father!" (35) But he said, "Your brother came deceitfully and took your blessing." (36) Esau said, "Isn't he rightly named Jacob? This is the second time he has taken advantage of me: He took my birthright, and now he's taken my blessing!" Then he asked, "Haven't you reserved any blessing for me?" (37) Isaac answered Esau, "I have made him lord over you and have made all his relatives his servants, and I have sustained him with grain and new wine. So what can I possibly do for you, my son?" (38) Esau said to his father, "Do you have only one blessing, my father? Bless me too, my father!" Then Esau wept aloud. (39) His father Isaac answered him, "Your dwelling will be away from the earth's richness, away from the dew of heaven above. (40) You will live by the sword and you will serve your brother. But when you grow restless, you will throw his yoke from off your neck." (41) Esau held a grudge against Jacob because of the blessing his father had given him. He said to himself, "The days of mourning for my father are near; then I will kill my brother Jacob." (42) When Rebekah was told what her older son Esau had said, she sent for her younger son Jacob and said to him, "Your brother Esau is planning to avenge himself by killing you. (43) Now then, my son, do what I say: Flee at once to my brother Laban in Harran. (44) Stay with him for a while until your brother's fury subsides. (45) When your brother is no longer angry with you and forgets what you did to him, I'll send word for you to come back from there. Why should I lose both of you in one day?" (46) Then Rebekah said to Isaac, "I'm disgusted with living because of these Hittite women. If Jacob takes a wife from among the women of this land, from Hittite women like these, my life will not be worth living."

Paul says that every blessing was conferred on Christ and due to the believer bearing the qualities of Christ and having "put on Christ" they are also blessed with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places in Christ Jesus:

> [Eph 1:3 NIV] (3) Praise be to the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us in the heavenly realms with every spiritual blessing in Christ.

So those "in Christ" are blessed with Christ with the whole of God's portion, his People, glorified Israel.

Update:

Paul's language "treasured possession" comes from Malachi. In it God promises that when he acts he will do so treating them as he treats Christ - again, because they will be in Christ. This confirms my comments about being blessed with every spiritual blessing "in Christ" ala Jacob inside Esau:

> **[Mal 3:17 NIV] (17) "On the day when I act," says the LORD Almighty, "they will be my treasured possession.** I will spare them, just as a father has compassion and spares his son who serves him.

[image: Isaac blessing Esau]

Related:

[What is it that Paul prays Ephesians will comprehend?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13961/what-is-it-that-paul-prays-ephesians-will-comprehend/30036?r=SearchResults&s=1|82.4875#30036)

Answer (score 0):

**What is the “His glorious inheritance” mentioned in Ephesians 1:18?**

> Ephesians 1:18 "having the eyes of your hearts enlightened, that you
>   may know what is the hope to which he has called you, what are the
>   riches of his glorious inheritance in the saints."

A more correct translation of Ephesians 1:18 is that  by the Complete Jewish Bible Bible which reads:

> 18 "I pray that he will give light to the eyes of your hearts, so that
>   you will understand the hope to which he has called you, what rich
>   glories there are in the inheritance he has promised his people."

The "Saints" are also referred to in the scriptures  as "Chosen Ones", "Little Flock" (Luke 12:32),"Least brothers "( Matt.25:40 NET),"Israel of God" (Galatians 6:15-16). e.t.c.

The Apostle Peter wrote his  epistles  addressed to the" Chosen Ones" or "Saints" as referred to by Paul in Ephesians 1:18

Aramaic Bible in Plain English, (1 Peter 1:1)

"Petraus, an Apostle of Yeshua The Messiah, to **The Chosen Ones** and Pilgrims who are scattered in Pontus and in Galatia, in Qapadoqia, in Asia and in Bithynia."

New Living Translation (1 Peter 1:1)

"This letter is from Peter, an apostle of Jesus Christ. I am writing to **God’s chosen people** who are living as foreigners in the provinces of Pontus, Galatia, Cappadocia, Asia, and Bithynia."

In his first epistle  Peter gives praise to God for the "glorious inheritance " granted to the chosen ones,  an inheritance that can never perish, spoil or fade. **This inheritance is kept in heaven for  them.**

1 Peter 1:3-6  (NET Bible)

Praise to God for a Living Hope Reserved in Heaven.

> 3" Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ! By his
>   great mercy he gave us new birth into a living hope through the
>   resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead, 4 that is, into an
>   inheritance imperishable, undefiled, and unfading. **It is reserved in
>   heaven for you,** 5 who by God’s power are protected through faith for a
>   salvation ready to be revealed in the last time. **6 This brings you
>   great joy, although you may have to suffer for a short time in various
>   trials."**

2 Peter 1:5-11  (NET Bible)

> 5 "For this very reason, make every effort to add to your faith
>   excellence, to excellence, knowledge; 6 to knowledge, self-control; to
>   self-control, perseverance; to perseverance, godliness; 7 to
>   godliness, brotherly affection; to brotherly affection, unselfish
>   love. 8 For if these things are really yours and are continually
>   increasing, they will keep you from becoming ineffective and
>   unproductive in your pursuit of knowing our Lord Jesus Christ more
>   intimately."
>
> 9 "But concerning the one who lacks such things—he is blind. That is
>   to say, he is nearsighted, since he has forgotten about the cleansing
>   of his past sins. 10 Therefore, brothers and sisters, make every
>   effort to be sure of your calling and election. For by doing this you
>   will never stumble into sin. 11 For thus an entrance into the eternal
>   kingdom of our Lord and Savior, Jesus Christ, will be richly provided
>   for you."

**1/ What did  Christ inherit?**

**Inherit  the Kingdom of his father David.( Luke 1:30-35)**

God sent the angel Gabriel from heaven and announced to Mary, that she will become the mother of God's son Jesus, and that he will  be given the throne of his father David, and that his kingdom  will be everlasting .Gabriel said to Mary:

Luke 1:30-35  (NASB)

30 "The angel said to her, “Do not be afraid, Mary; for you have found favor with God. 31 And behold, you will conceive in your womb and bear a son, and you shall name Him Jesus. **32 He will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High; and the Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David;** 33 and He will reign over the house of Jacob forever, and His kingdom will have no end**.” 34 Mary said to the angel, “How can this be, since I am a virgin?” 35 The angel answered and said to her, “The Holy Spirit will come upon you, and the power of the Most High will overshadow you; and for that reason the holy Child shall be called the Son of God. ( Read from  Luke 1:26-37)**

**2/ From whom did He inherit?**

From God the Father, The  Covenant God made with King David. (2 Samuel 7:11-16, Luke 22:28-29)

2 Samuel 7:11-16 (NASB)

> 11 "Even from the day that I commanded judges to be over My people
>   Israel; and I will give you rest from all your enemies. The Lord also
>   declares to you that the Lord will make a house for you. 12 When your
>   days are complete and you lie down with your fathers, I will raise up
>   your descendant after you, who will come forth from you, and I will
>   establish his kingdom. 13 He shall build a house for My name, and I
>   will establish the throne of his kingdom forever."
>
> 14 "I will be a father to him and he will be a son to Me; when he
>   commits iniquity, I will correct him with the rod of men and the
>   strokes of the sons of men, 15 but My loving kindness shall not depart
>   from him, as I took it away from Saul, whom I removed from before you.
>   16 Your house and your kingdom shall endure before [c]Me forever; your
>   throne shall be established forever.”

Daniel 7:13-14  (NASB)

The Son of Man (Jesus) Presented to the Ancient of Days ( Matthew 19:28, and 20:28)

> 13 “I kept looking in the night visions, And behold, with the clouds
>   of heaven One like a Son of Man was coming, And He came up to the
>   Ancient of Days And was presented before Him. 14 “And to Him was given
>   dominion, Glory and [a]a kingdom, That all the peoples, nations and
>   men of every [b]language Might serve Him. His dominion is an
>   everlasting dominion Which will not pass away; And His kingdom is one 
>   Which will not be destroyed.

**Jesus speaks of two covenants, one between him and God his Father, and the other one with his faithful followers.**

Luke 22:28-29 (NASB)

> 28 “You are those who have stood by Me in My trials; 29 and just as My
>   Father has granted Me a kingdom, I grant you.

**3 What are the riches of it?**

Caused them to be born again for a heavenly inheritance which is imperishable and undefiled,(1 Peter 1:3-4) and to rule as kings and priests upon the earth.(Rev. 5:10)

1 Peter 1:3-4  (NASB)

> 3 "Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who
>   according to His great mercy has caused us to be born again to a
>   living hope through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead, **4
>   to obtain an inheritance which is imperishable and undefiled and will
>   not fade away, reserved in heaven for you."**

Paul wrote to his close friend Timothy "if we endure we will reign with him" ( 2  Tim. 2:12)Yes,Paul , Timothy and others selected by God will rule together with Jesus  as priests and reign over the earth in the heavenly Kingdom.(Rev 5:9-10)

Revelation 5:9-10 NASB

> 9 "And they *sang a new song, saying, “Worthy are You to take the
>   [j]book and to break its seals; for You were slain, and purchased for
>   God with Your blood men from every tribe and tongue and people and
>   nation. 10 “You have made them to be a kingdom and priests to our God;
>   and they will reign upon the earth."

2 Timothy 2:12  (NASB)

**> 12 "If we endure, we will also reign with Him,  If we deny Him, He

> also will deny us."**

**4/ How do the saints experience it?**

By means of His spirit, God dwells among the holy ones/saints  and walks among them.  (2  Cor. 6:16) Christians are admonished to present their bodies as a holy sacrifice acceptable to God. (Romans 12:1)

1 Corinthians 3:16-17  (NASB)

> 16 "Do you not know that you are a temple of God and that the Spirit
>   of God dwells in you? 17 If any man destroys the temple of God, God
>   will destroy him, for the [c]temple of God is holy, and [d]that is
>   what you are."

2 Corinthians 6:16 (NASB)

> 16 "Or what agreement has the temple of God with idols? For we are the
>   temple of the living God; just as God said,“I will dwell in them and
>   walk among them; And I will be their God, and they shall be My
>   people."

1 Peter 2:5 New American Standard Bible (NASB)

> 5 "You also, as living stones, [a]are being built up as a spiritual
>   house for a holy priesthood, to offer up spiritual sacrifices
>   acceptable to God through Jesus Christ."

Romans 12:1  (NASB)

Dedicated Service

> 12 "Therefore I urge you, brethren, by the mercies of God, to present
>   your bodies a living and holy sacrifice, acceptable to God, which is
>   your spiritual service of worship."

Comment: The passage in 1 Peter is the inheritance of the saints but the Ephesian passage is God’s inheritance. Notice HIS glorious inheritance. You are conflating the two inheritances

Comment: Nihi  Sine Deo . Much appreciate that you brought it to my attention , after reading the chapter , in context  the translation I quoted is not the best. A better translation is that of the "The Complete Jewish Bible" the NIRV and the CEV. The CJB reads: I pray that he will give light to the eyes of your hearts, so that you will understand the hope to which he has called you, what rich glories there are in the inheritance he has promised his people,(Ephesians 1:18)

Comment: Just stick with the original Greek    You might have found a translation that suits your preference but that’s not the point.

Comment: @Nihi Sine Deo: I will cite you my Greek Bible which gives a similar rendering as the CJB.1:18b " πόσο λαμπρή και πλούσια είναι η κληρονομιά που εχεί ετοιμασεί για τους δικούς του.(United Bible Societies-Athens 1985) Such a rendering is in harmony with the scriptures , compare : " Do not be afraid, little flock, for your Father has chosen gladly to give you the kingdom." Luke 12:32 "He has made us to be a kingdom, priests to [a]His God and Father—to Him be the glory and the dominion forever. Rev 1:6.  Luke 12:32, John 10:14, Heb 12:28, James 2:5, Daniel 7:27, Luke 22;28-30.

Comment: I don’t think you understand @OzzieNicolas v11 speaks of the inheritance of the saints but v18 speaks of God’s inheritance. You are arguing a mute point. I already agree that the saints have an inheritance that’s a given but you can’t therefore reinterpret v18 to mean the inheritance of the saints. Show me from the Greek why you think the grammar is claiming the inheritance is the saints’ and not God’s.

Comment: In English it doesn’t say what is the glorious inheritance TO the saints but IN the saints. The glorious inheritance is His and it’s found IN the saints.

Comment: Comment appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"**πλοῦτος τῆς δόξης**" 
the riches of the glory
Rom. 9:23; Eph. 1:18; 3:16; Col. 1:27

to whom God did will to make known what [is] the riches of the glory of this secret among the nations -- which is Christ in you, the hope of the glory, Colossians 1:27 Young's Literal Translation (YLT)

the riches of the glory=of this secret among the nations=**which is Christ in you**=the hope of the glory

Examine the syntactic structure of Greek sentence.
τίς ὁ πλοῦτος τῆς δόξης / τῆς κληρονομίας 
Acts 23:9; Eph. 1:18; Col. 1:27; Heb. 5:12

---

"**ἐλπίδι τῆς κλήσεως**" Eph. 4:4 e 1:18 “ hope of vocation” = perfection (Eph. 4:12)

---

And now I entrust you to God and to the message of his grace. This message is able to build you up and give you an inheritance **among all those who are sanctified**.Acts 20:32 NET

to open their eyes so that they turn from darkness to light and from the power of Satan to God, so that they may receive forgiveness of sins and a share**56** **among those who are sanctified by faith in me.’ Acts 26:18 NET@ 56=t**n Or “and an inheritance.” 
interesting variable.

---

when he comes **to be glorified among his saints** and **admired[n] on that day among all who have believed**—and you did in fact believe our testimony. 2 Thessalonians 1:10

**to be glorified among his saints**
**admired[n] on that day among all who have believed**

---

Who are the Saints of God?

So then you are no longer foreigners and noncitizens, but you are **fellow citizens with the saints** and members of God’s household, Ephesians 2:19 New English Translation (NET Bible)

To me—less than the least of all the saints[s]—this grace was given,[t] to proclaim to the Gentiles the unfathomable riches of Christ  Ephesians 3:8

the saints of Eph. 1:18 were converted Jews?

1) Ephesians 2:11-2:22;

2) Ephesians 3:1;

3) Ephesians 3:6.

An allusion to the   Matthew 17:1-5 and  Acts 7:38.

---

what the relation between Ephesians 1:13-14 and 2 Corinthians 5:1-5

---

**the pronoun "his" refers to the Gentiles in Eph. 1:18?**

---

what did Gentiles have inherit?

**the Inner Christ.**

From whom did they inherit?

**of the Jews**

What are the riches of it?

**the perfection.**

How does the Gentiles experience it?

to open their eyes so that they turn from darkness to light and from the power of Satan to God, so that they may receive forgiveness of sins **and an inheritance** among those who are sanctified by faith in me.’ NEt Bible Acts 26:18
.
The advancement of the variable classification in Acts 26:18 is evident.